# A better way to say "endure the difficulties that has to come"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Writing an essay about decision making.

Is there a better way to say "that has to come"?

Comment: You must be brave!!!

Comment: Writing advice is off-topic here. Also, your sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Saying “endure the **difficulties** that **has** to come” is not correct, because “has” is only used when the noun is singular. If you want “difficulties” to be more than one (as opposed to “difficulty”) you must use **have**.

> Endure the *difficulties* that *have* to come.
>
> Endure the *difficulty* that *has* to come.

And if you are looking for other ways to say it:

> Endure the difficulties that *must/will* come.
>
> Endure the difficulties that *approach*.
>
> Endure the difficulties that *are imminent*.

Hope this helps!